# How to parse RSS feed in React Native 0.63?

Tags: react-native, xml-parsing, rss, rss-reader

While I was searching for a solution on Google, I found this react-native-rss-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rss-parser).

It has this usage example:

```
import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser';

return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(rss.title);
    console.log(rss.items.length);
  });
```

But when I try

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
      .then((rss) => {
        console.log(rss.title);
        console.log(rss.items.length);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);
```

It gives me this error:

```
[TypeError: _this.getElementTextContentArray is not a function. (In '_this.getElementTextContentArray(node, tagName, namespace)', '_this.getElementTextContentArray' is undefined)]
```

What can I do? Does anyone know any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue related to the newest version 1.5.0.

I opened a github ticket:
https://github.com/jameslawler/react-native-rss-parser/issues/16

Right now you can use v1.4.0 of react-native-rss-parser to make it work.

```
yarn add react-native-rss-parser@1.4.0
```